# Get value of attr after AJAX call in React.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, d3.js, reactjs

I created a pie chart with d3.js first with static values. However, now I want to recieve data from my server and update the data of the pie chart with it.

For this I do a AJAX call in my React component, Here the code :

```
import React from 'react';

class RingChart extends React.Component {
  loadPieChart() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({dataPie: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {dataPie: []};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadPieChart();
    setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div className="chart">
      <h3>Title chart</h3>
      <div className="ring" data-valid={this.state.dataPie.nbValid} data-unvalid={this.state.dataPie.nbUnValid} data-pourcentage={this.state.dataPie.pourcentage}></div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RingChart;
```

I have a js script which create the pie chart, and in this script I want to collect values of data attributes like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var valid = $(".ring").data("valid");
  console.log(valid);
});
```

However the console says that valid is undefined, and when I execute this code directly in the console, the correct value is return.

So I think that the script is called before that the AJAX call is finished. But I don't know how to solve this in React.js

My js script and d3.js are called in index.html ... I think it's a bad way in React.js but I didn't manage to do it in an other way.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>React.js using NPM, Babel6 and Webpack</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.2/marked.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="public/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/ringChart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Anyone have a solution ?

Comment: move `$(".ring").data("valid");` into `componentDidMount` and in your ajax success function as well.

Comment: @azium Same It works when I move it in success function, but I need this value in my js script to create correctly my pie chart.

Comment: Are you using webpack or browserify? Why don't you make your `ringChart` a module and bundle it together with your react code.

Comment: I use webpack, but I don't understand very well how it works unfortunately. I have no idea how to bundle it with my react code. You mean create a react component with my js script and call it in RingChart ??

Comment: No I mean to export some function from `ringChart.js` so that you can pass the data to it. `export default function makeChart(data) { .. }` then inside React file `import makeChart from './ringChart'`. Then when the data comes back you can just call this function. `success: data => makeChart(data)`

Comment: You don't need the intermediate step of saving the data to a `data-` attribute that way, just pass it to whoever needs it.

Comment: Ok yes good idea, but what is the step to export my function ? In my ringChart.js I do : export function default makeChart(data) { } like you say. But How webpack know to get the correct path with import .. from './ringChart' ?

Comment: the paths are relative to the file that's importing. If your files are in the same folder like `js/component.js` and `js/ringChart.js` then the import path is `./ringChart`. If you don't write `./` or `../` to go back one folder, then webpack will look in your `node_modules` folder for 3rd party stuff like React.